# Express the Induced Curvature Forms on the Pullback Bundle through the connection forms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, connections, pullback

This question came up while reading Differential Geometry by Loring W.Tu.

Suppose $\pi: E \to M$ is a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ vector bundle. And $f:N \to M$ a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ map of manifolds. Let $\nabla$ be a connection on $E$ with connection matrix $\omega_e$ relative to a local frame $e$ for $E$. Then there is a unique connection $\nabla'$ on the pullback bundle $f^{*}E \to N$ whose connection matrix relative to the frame $f^{*}e$ is $f^{*}(\omega_e)$.

That makes sense so far.

The author then writes:
The induced curvature form on $f^{*}E$ is therefore
$f^{*} \Omega_e = f^{*} \omega_e + \frac{1}{2} [f^{*} \omega_e, f^{*} \omega_e]$.
Now I don't understand why the induced curvature forms are $f^{*} \Omega_e$ or why this formula holds.

Comment: Did you mean $[f^*\omega_e,f^*\omega_e]$ instead of $[f^*\omega_e,\omega_e]$? And $d(f^*\omega_e)$ instand of the first $f^*\omega_e$?

Comment: Ah yes thank you I meant to write $[f^{*}\omega_e, f^{*} \omega_e]$ but the first term is exactly as in the book. (See chapter 23.6). I do know the formula $\Omega = d\omega + \omega \wedge \omega$. And I reviewed the definition of $[\cdot, \cdot]$ in the book and $[a,b] = a \wedge b + b \wedge a$. So the last part fits

Comment: Maybe a typo by the author ?

Comment: Probably: you can see that $f^*\omega_e$ and $[f^*\omega_e,f^*\omega_e]$ are not tensors of the same type, so adding them may not be a good idea there!

Comment: Thank you ! That's true, adding a 2-form to a 1-form doesn't make sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I think that there is a typo, either in your question or in the book. The right equality should be this
$$f^*\Omega_e = d(f^*\omega_e) + \frac{1}{2}[f^*\omega_e,f^*\omega_e]$$
or this
$$
f^*\Omega_e = f^*d\omega_e + \frac{1}{2}f^*[\omega_e,\omega_e],
$$
which are pretty much the same thing, since the pullback commutes with both the exterior differential $d$ and the bracket $[\cdot,\cdot]$. These equalities are trivial, since by definition, $\Omega_e = d\omega_e + \frac{1}{2}[\omega_e,\omega_e]$ (apply the pullback through $f$ to that equality).

The real question is: Why is this the curvature form of $\nabla'$ on $f^*E$ associated to the frame $f^*e$?
The answer is because, as you said, the connection matrix $\omega_{f^*e}$ associated to the frame $f^*e$ is $f^*\omega_e$. Therefore
$$\Omega_{f^*e} :=d\omega_{f^*e} + \frac{1}{2}[\omega_{f^*e},\omega_{f^*e}]\underset{\omega_{f^*e}=f^*\omega_e}{=} d(f^*\omega_e)+\frac{1}{2}[f^*\omega_e,f^*\omega_e]$$
which has already been shown above to be equal to $f^*\Omega_e$.